# Google App Script (.gs) Difference Between Input Handling of Custom Function and Named Function When Called Identically From Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to posting technical questions so please bare with me. While my application I would like to keep to myself, I have the following situation. I am driving a series of cars. I log each day what car I drive in worksheet range A (not a named range). This data lives on Sheet 1. The header row is not included in range A.

| Date | Car |
| --- | --- |
| 12/14/2023 | King Midget Model III |
| 12/15/2023 | Model T |

I also log the last time I changed the tires as range B (not a named range). This data lives on Sheet 2. The header row is not included in range B.

| Date | Car |
| --- | --- |
| 10/01/2022 | King Midget Model III |
| 11/16/2023 | Model T |

I then have a third range that captures rides since last tire change as range C (not a named range). This data lives on Sheet 1.

| Car | Days Since Tire Change |
| --- | --- |
| King Midget Model III | 1 |
| Model T | 1 |

I created a App Script (.gs) function called RidesSinceChange. On Sheet1 it is called as the following:

=RidesSinceChange("CarName" as single cell selection, "TireChangeData" as Range B, "DrivingData" as Range A)

This script works great as written. However, I want end users to be able to see exactly how to utilize the function. The way Google App Script documentation says to do this is to use Named Functions. I created a named function (TIREWEAR) that was identically called, but on the backend calls the custom function: RidesSinceChanged. However, this outputted an error.

Upon looking at the first error, it seems it's reading in the "Range B" and "Range C" data as strings instead of as objects. There are NO differences I can see between the calls. Does anyone have any idea how to change my scripting to troubleshoot this discrepancy on input handling? I know .gs is based on .js so I don't think I can force the input to be interpreted as an Object.

Please note, I have read alot of forums on this topic. And some mention it is possible to have better handling if instead of a named function a button is pressed which can cause the recalculation to occur. I don't want to use a button. There are 1000s of applications of this "Days Since Tire Change" model so I cannot create 1000s of buttons within the same google workbook.

Also I'm aware I can create a Named Function with an intricate "COUNTIF" routine for the above application. This will not work with my more intricate problems.

I greatly apologize for the constraints and appreciate any feedback anyone may have! Please take it easy on this first time poster if there's anything dumb I may have missed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really use cell or custom functions much at all but I believe the inputs for a custom function inserted into cell return the values of the cells written in a1 notation.  Where if you call the function as a named function that a1notation is evaluated as a string.

So I have function that can operated both ways.

```
function CUSTOMTEST(input) {
  var vs;
  if (!Array.isArray(input)) {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
    vs = sh.getRange(input).getValues()
  } else {
    vs = input
  }
  return vs;
}
```

If you run the below test function which serves as and intermediate function

```
function testcustomtest() {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(CUSTOMTEST("A1:E6")));
}
```

You will get the following:

```
[["COL1","COL2","COL3","COL4","COL5"],["A2","B2","C2","D2","E2"],["A3","B3","C3","D3","E3"],["A4","B4","C4","D4","E4"],["A5","B5","C5","D5","E5"],["A6","B6","C6","D6","E6"]]
```

When I insert `=CUSTOMTEST(A1:J6)` into K1 of the same sheet:

|  | K | L | M | N | O |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 |
| 2 | A2 | B2 | C2 | D2 | E2 |
| 3 | A3 | B3 | C3 | D3 | E3 |
| 4 | A4 | B4 | C4 | D4 | E4 |
| 5 | A5 | B5 | C5 | D5 | E5 |
| 6 | A6 | B6 | C6 | D6 | E6 |

The data in this sheet between A2:J26 is the A1Notation of the cell.  In the latter case since the adjacent cells are empty it fills the surround cells with that same data. You many already know more than I know about if so I apologize for my feeble attempt.

Comment: Thank you! Using this process, it helped me identify that there was indeed a variable mis-named in the named function as called in the custom function. I have created a simulated google doc with the functioning code: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hOJc9RyEDFeePT1rsNL9hNpQtkfR1P13MYBp6zPlETg/edit#gid=0

Comment: You might really enjoy some like that a lot more if you turn it into a webapp so that you can access it on your phone,  When I start something like that I always build into a dialog first.

Comment: Thank you, for other projects that sounds good. Do you have any preferred resources for me to learn that?

Comment: Actually one of the best  resources is hanging around this site offering answers and reading other peoples answers.  I've learned lot here.  I've improved my Javascript a lot and I knew a bit about css and html.  There's still a lot I don't know about the API's but for my interests I pretty happy for the mot part with the core services.